# Get the contents of a cell that is next to the maximum value in a certain range

Tags: google-sheets

I ran into a problem that I couldn't solve. Suppose we have a table:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | SHOP | PSU NAME | POWER | W/USD | LINK | PRICE |
| 21 | abc | abc | number | number | link | number |
| 22 | abc | abc | number | number | link | number |
| 23 | abc | abc | number | number | link | number |
| 24 | abc | abc | number | number | link | number |

And I would like to find MAX value in range D21:D24 and then get link (cell next to this max value) and display it in other cell. Finding MAX value of D column is easy, but I don't know how to "move" to other cell after that.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: 'but I don't know how to "move" to other cell after that.' People might not understand what you mean, as it is not clear where you want it. Show in your question what you want as well, people will be quicker to help out.

Comment: By 'but I don't know how to "move" to other cell after that.' I mean, that I don't know how to get cell's adrress.

Comment: Welcome! It seems you are trying to build a formula similar to `=INDEX(E21:E,MATCH(MAX(D21:D),D21:D,0))`?